# Creating single .xib for different UITableViewCell classes

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, xib

I am facing a problem.

I have a `NNVerticalStackTableViewCell.xib` file and its corresponding `NNVerticalStackTableViewCell.swift` file.

Code for `NNVerticalStackTableViewCell.swift` file:

```
class NNVerticalStackTableViewCell: UITableViewCell
{
    //MARK: Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var verticalStack: NNVerticalStackView!
    
    //MARK: Internal Properties
    var titleString : String?
        {
        set{
            self.titleLabel.text = newValue
        }
        get{
            return self.titleLabel.text
        }
    }
    
    //MARK: View Lifecycle Methods
    override func awakeFromNib()
    {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.titleLabel.text = nil
    }
    
    //MARK: Internal Methods
    func addViewsInVerticalStack(viewsArray : [UIView])
    {
        for view in viewsArray
        {
            self.verticalStack.insertStackItem(view)
        }
    }
}
```

Interface for `NNVerticalStackTableViewCell.xib` file

[image]

with `class name` as : `NNVerticalStackTableViewCell` and `cell identifier` as : `NNVerticalStackTableViewCell`

Now I created a subclass of `NNVerticalStackTableViewCell` as:

```
class NNPropertiesUnderProjectTableViewCell: NNVerticalStackTableViewCell
{
    //MARK: Internal Properties
    var completionHandler : ((NNSearchPreference) -> Void)?
    
    //MARK: Internal Methods
    func configureCell(_ propertiesUnderProjectArray : [[String : Any]])
    {
        var viewsArray = [UIView]()
        for dict in propertiesUnderProjectArray
        {
            let elementView = NNPropertiesUnderProjectElementView.loadFromNib()
            elementView?.configureViewWith(buttonTitleString: dict["displayString"] as! String, searchPreference: dict["searchPreference"] as! NNSearchPreference, completionHandler: {[weak self] (searchPreference) in
                if let handler = self?.completionHandler
                {
                    handler(searchPreference)
                }
                })
            viewsArray.addObject(elementView)
        }
        self.addViewsInVerticalStack(viewsArray: viewsArray)
    }
}
```

Now what I want to do is use `NNPropertiesUnderProjectTableViewCell` class with `NNVerticalStackTableViewCell.xib` interface.

Similar to `NNPropertiesUnderProjectTableViewCell` class I have many other classes that uses the same interface as `NNVerticalStackTableViewCell.xib` and customize it accordingly.

In my `ViewController`, I registered `NNVerticalStackTableViewCell.xib` and then creating the cell as:

```
self.tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "NNVerticalStackTableViewCell"), forCellReuseIdentifier: "NNVerticalStackTableViewCell")


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
            let propertiesUnderProjectCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NNVerticalStackTableViewCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! NNPropertiesUnderProjectTableViewCell
    }
```

But, I am getting the exception:

```
Could not cast value of type 'NNVerticalStackTableViewCell' (0x100945878) to 'NNPropertiesUnderProjectTableViewCell' (0x100949330).
```

How can I solve the problem? I want to use single `.xib` and do not want to repeat the code.

Comment: Can you, please, show an example of multiple classes working with the same xib file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can, but, instead of using the `UITableViewCell`, use similar `UIView`

Create a xib for the cell content view, give it a class (like `CellView`).
In each cell class, get the `CellView` with `loadNibNamed` and set it as the cell content view, then you can freely change the property of the `CellView` and use it as other cell class's content view

Maybe there's better solution, but this is how i do it for similar looking `UIViewController`, you might also try cell xib without class set in storyboard and try to load it and see if the error still persist or not

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that as the `registerNib:` expect the same instance of the exact registered view.

From here you can do is replicate `NNVerticalStackTableViewCell.xib` and retain `NNVerticalStackTableViewCell.swift` as your base class.

then create something like `NNPropertiesUnderProjectTableViewCell.xib` where it holds the exact same view as before `NNVerticalStackTableViewCell.xib` with your added controls. Then subclass it to `NNPropertiesUnderProjectTableViewCell.swift` with a unique identifer: `NNPropertiesUnderProjectTableViewCell`.

in which `NNPropertiesUnderProjectTableViewCell` is a subclas of `NNVerticalStackTableViewCell`.

From here, just add your additional controls unique to `NNPropertiesUnderProjectTableViewCell` class.

Comment: Ya I used the same approach. But I was hoping for some alternative.

Answer (score 2):

You can Do like this if you want to use tableViewCell.xib in multiple Time.
First Go to File and Create New File (Cocoa Touch Class).

[image: CocoaTouch Class]

Create TableViewCell File With .xib

[image: TableViewCell]

Now Simple Create your Custom Cell Design

[image: Design]

Now Add this code in your File TableViewCell.swift

[image]

Now just add identifier in your tableView Cell like this (where you want to add this custom TableviewCell)

[image: cell]

Now just take it as your Cell Like this..

[image: Table]

And Bingo You got it..

Now just add cell as! TableViewCell in any TableViewController File (You got same results with same Design.)

[image: OutPut1]

Here of Click First (Load First TableViewController)

[image: FirstTable]

On Click Second (Load Second TableViewController)

[image: SecondTable View]

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you can't do exactly what you're trying to do because the class name is in the XIB so you always get an instance of the base class, not any of your subclasses.

The suggestion from @Tj3n is a good one, extract the common part into a reusable view and in your superclass initialisation create an instance of that view and add it. Now, when you instantiate a subclass and it calls super the common element will be initialised and usable by the subclass.

In other words, use composition to achieve your goal, not inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

NNPropertiesUnderProjectTableViewCell is not register for the Cellidentifier.